# laravel 5.5 CRUD with pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, crud

I'm trying to make a CRUD using 2 tables and a pivot table in Laravel 5.5.

I created models, controllers, and migration this way:

First Step: Managing the Lang used in the application

```
php artisan make:controller LangController --resource -model=Lang
php artisan make:migration create_Langs_table
```

Second Step: Managing the Articles created in the article

```
php artisan make:controller ArticleController --resource -model=Article
php artisan make:migration create_articles_table
```

Third step: I create the pivot table

```
php artisan make:migration create_article_lang_table
```

Fourth step: I created the routes

```
Route::resource('/articles', 'ArticleController');
```

Fifth step: I created the relations in the models:

In Article model:

```
public function langs(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Lang')->withPivot('name','shortname','description')->withTimestamps();
}
```

In Lang model:

```
public function articles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article')->withPivot('name','shortname','description')->withTimestamps();
}
```

I also modified the pivot table because it contains specific fields

```
class CreateLangSectorTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('article_lang', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('lang_id');
            $table->integer('article_id')->index('FK_ARTICLE');
            $table->string('name', 80)->nullable();
            $table->string('shortname', 40)->nullable();
            $table->text('description', 65535)->nullable();
            $table->primary(['lang_id','sector_id']);
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('langs_sectors');
    }
}
```

From there I'm stuck when I want to create my CRUD in the ArticleController. I tried to make modifications in the ArticleController but without success. So I deleted everything.

```
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    // Display a listing of the resource.
    public function index() {
    }

    // Show the form for creating a new resource.
    public function create() {
    }
    // Store a newly created resource in storage.
    public function store(Request $request) {
    }

    // Display the specified resource.
    public function show($id) {
    }

    // Show the form for editing the specified resource.
    public function edit($id) {
    }

    // Update
    public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    }

    // Remove the specified resource from storage.
    public function destroy($id) {
    }
}
```

I want in the "index":

- to show a table with: name, shortname, description
- to filter by lang or display article in a specific language

In the "create"

- I want to create an article in a lang
- I want to create an article which is a translation of another article

I really like using Laravel but I also need more practice :)
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want in the "index" to show a table with: name, shortname, description and to filter by lang or display article in a specific language

Load the data and pass it to the view:

```
$lang = Lang::find($id);
$articles = $lang->articles()->get();
return view('articles.index', ['articles' => $articles]);
```

Display the data:

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
    {{ $article->pivot->name }}
    {{ $article->pivot->shortname }}
@endforeach
```

> In the "create" I want to create an article in a lang and I want to create an article which is a translation of another article

Make sure you've added the [`$fillable`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment) array to the `Article` model. Create an article:

```
$lang = Lang::find($id);
$article = $lang->articles()->create(['columnInArticlesTable' => $request->something]);
```

Then create an translation by using the [`attach()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) method:

```
$lang->articles()->attach($article->id, ['name' => $request->name, 'shortname' => $request->shortname]);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ... but I receive an "Undefined variable: id" when i go to the index...

Comment: @davidvera I gave you an example of how to handle these things. You can't expect full implementation of these features from someone.

Comment: thanks for your help ... i will try to find out a solution ... it should be much more easier from there ...

Comment: I found out my mistake ... it was very stupid indeed ...

It was here : 
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Lang')->withPivot('name','shortname','description')->withTimestamps();

I just don't have Timestamp in the pivot table ... Now it works fine !

Answer (score 1):

I solved partially my issue concerning this question ... Concerning the index method I have :

```
public function index() {
    $countLang = Lang::count();
    $countArticle = Article::count();
    for ($i=1; $i<=$countLang; $i++) {
        $lang = Lang::find($i);
        $article[$i] = $lang->article()->get();
    }
    return view('admin.pages.articles.index', compact('articles', 'countLang', 'countSector'));
}
```

It generate the right SQL requests ... But i still have issue to get all the datas in the view ... I should be able to see each article in each langs ...

Answer (score 0):

Finally i made this in my view :

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
    @for($i=0; $i < $countArticle; $i++)
        {{  $article[$i]->pivot->sectname }}<br>
    @endfor
@endforeach
```

And i display the data ...